# MySql Error when adding table

Tags: mysql, sql

this is a sql query i'm trying to execute but it fails with this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
>   for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
>    `passhash` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
>    `permission` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT' at line 3:

And this is the query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Maestros`;

CREATE TABLE `Maestros` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `passhash` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `permission` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `activo` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY (`passhash`)
) COMMENT 'Tabla que contiene la informacion de los maestros';
```

Answer (score 1):

`varchar` should have a length associated with it and there can be only one `TimeStamp` with a default:

```
CREATE TABLE `Maestros` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `passhash` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `permission` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` TIMESTAMP,
  `activo` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY (`passhash`)
) COMMENT 'Tabla que contiene la informacion de los maestros';
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bceda) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The problems in your MySQL query are as below:
- Whenever you specify varchar as the datatype you need to have max size of the column defined i.e. varchar(50) instead of simply varchar [where 50 is the no of characters allowed in column]
- You cannot have the 'DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' constraint used for more than one column in a single query

The modified query is as below...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Maestros`;

CREATE TABLE `Maestros` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `passhash` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `permission` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `activo` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY (`passhash`)
) COMMENT 'Tabla que contiene la informacion de los maestros';
```